# Is there a way to build CSV file out of command line key-value pair output with different separators in Unix?

Tags: shell, csv, unix, awk, key-value

I've raw log snippets being dumped on the console as output for custom command:

```
bash$ custom-command
current-capacity: 3%, buffer: 1024, not-used/total: 10/10, IsEnabled: 0. Up since Thu Jun 23 11:54:14 2022
current-capacity: 0%, buffer: 1024, not-used/total: 25/25, IsEnabled: 0. Up since Thu Jun 23 11:54:14 2022
current-capacity: 0%, buffer: 1024, not-used/total: 15/15, IsEnabled: 1. Up since Thu Jun 23 11:54:14 2022
```

I need have CSV format like below to capture the status in real-time based on certain criterias, I can then redirect the output to CSV file at regular interval before loading into SQL database.

```
current-capacity, buffer, not-used/total, IsEnabled, Up since
3%, 1024, 10/10, 0, Thu Jun 23 11:54:14 2022
0%, 1024, 25/, 0, Thu Jun 23 11:54:14 2022
0%, 1024, 10/10, 0, Thu Jun 23 11:54:14 2022
```

I've tried AWK but still facing issue since it's comma seperated for most part except `IsEnabled: 0` ends with `.` then the `Uptime`. Is there a way? I'm quite new to awk.

Comment: Please check the expected output you posted as it's not obvious how you'd get those 3rd field output values in the last 2 lines from the sample input you provided.

Comment: you solved? If so, mark the answer you used.
You have to take care of this site and how it works

Answer (score 1):

```
 awk -F' :|, |: ' -v OFS="," '
    NR==1{ 
        print $1,$3,$5,$7,"Up since"
    }
    {
        print $2,$4,$6,gensub(/([0-1])\. ?Up since ?(.*)/, "\\1,\\2", 1, $8)
    }' file

current-capacity,buffer,not-used/total,IsEnabled,Up since
3%,1024,10/10,0,Thu Jun 23 11:54:14 2022
0%,1024,25/25,0,Thu Jun 23 11:54:14 2022
0%,1024,15/15,1,Thu Jun 23 11:54:14 2022
```

---

```
awk -F' :|, |: ' '
 function formatRow(r){
    return gensub(/([0-1])\. ?(Up since)/, "\\1, \\2:", 1, r)
 }
 NR==1{
     $0 = formatRow($0) 
     for(i=1;i<=NF-1;i+=2) printf (i==NF-1 ? "%s\n" : "%s,"), $i 
 }
 {
     $0 = formatRow($0)
     for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) printf (i==NF ? "%s\n" : "%s,"), $i
}' file

current-capacity,buffer,not-used/total,IsEnabled,Up since
3%,1024,10/10,0,Thu Jun 23 11:54:14 2022
0%,1024,25/25,0,Thu Jun 23 11:54:14 2022
0%,1024,15/15,1,Thu Jun 23 11:54:14 2022
```

Comment: Clearly a better solution compared to my suggestion. Could you update the answer with link to explain the `:|, |:` part ? I know what it does, just don't find in the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Field-Separators) what you do here exactly.

Comment: @MyICQ. alternation multichar delimiters with regex or `|`. if delimiter is ` :` or `, ` or `: `

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `match` statement in `gawk` to capture all fields using regular expressions, because your input data is formatted same way.

Something like this will do the needed:

```
BEGIN{
   # set output separator to comma space
   OFS=", "
   
   # define the regular expression to capture needed
   # See https://regex101.com/r/K4wYoB/1
   #
   #   ([^,])   captures all until next comma, not including comma
   #   (.)      captures single character
   #   (.*)     at the end, captures remaining
   #
   #   did not use full words, since it was not needed.
   #   
   myregexp="y: ([^,]*).*r: ([^,]*).*al: ([^,]*).*led: (.).*ce (.*)"
   
   # print header for output
   print "current-capacity, buffer, not-used/total, IsEnabled, Up since"
}

# loop lines. Skipping header line
NR>1{

   # capture data fields
   match($0, myregexp, a)
   
   # print the line from "a" array
   print a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just writing a regex that matches the output and transforming it.

```
sed -E 's/current-capacity: (.*)%, buffer: (.*), not-used/total: (.*), IsEnabled: (.*). Up since (.*)/\1%,\2,\3,\4/'
```

Comment: That won't print the header line.

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[:,] "; OFS=", " }
match($0,/\. [^ ]+ [^ ]+/) {
    $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART-1) "," substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1) ":" substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
}
NR == 1 {
    for ( i=1; i<NF; i+=2 ) {
        printf "%s%s", $i, (i<(NF-1) ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}
{
    for ( i=2; i<=NF; i+=2 ) {
        printf "%s%s", $i, (i<NF ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
current-capacity, buffer, not-used/total, IsEnabled, Up since
3%, 1024, 10/10, 0, Thu Jun 23 11:54:14 2022
0%, 1024, 25/25, 0, Thu Jun 23 11:54:14 2022
0%, 1024, 15/15, 1, Thu Jun 23 11:54:14 2022
```

In the above the first step is using `match() { ... }` to make the `. Up since Thu` field at the end of each input line use the same `,` and `:` separators as the rest of the input `, Up since: Thu` so the rest of the code parsing the now consistent input is easy.

Answer (score 0):

The input format, is one of [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-miller/) input formats

If you run simply

```
mlr --ocsv --ips : clean-whitespace input.txt
```

you will have

```
current-capacity,buffer,not-used/total,IsEnabled
3%,1024,10/10,0. Up since Thu Jun 23 11:54:14 2022
0%,1024,25/25,0. Up since Thu Jun 23 11:54:14 2022
0%,1024,15/15,1. Up since Thu Jun 23 11:54:14 2022
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{m,g}awk '
NR == (NF=NF)^_ { printf("%s,%s,%s,%s%.00s, Up since\n", 
                              $(__=_^=_<_),  $(_+=++__), 
                         $(_+=__), $(_+__),  FS = FS"|(, )+") 
} {
    for(_^=!__;_<NF;_+=__) {
        $_=___ 
    }   $(+___)=$(_-=_)
} 
sub("^ *(, )*",___,$!(NF = NF))' FS='[.] Up since |[,:][ \t]+' OFS=', '
```

|

```
current-capacity, buffer, not-used/total, IsEnabled, Up since
3%, 1024, 10/10, 0, Thu Jun 23 11:54:14 2022
0%, 1024, 25/25, 0, Thu Jun 23 11:54:14 2022
0%, 1024, 15/15, 1, Thu Jun 23 11:54:14 2022
```